# Aggregating Collectd measures using Statsd

Tags: metrics, statsd, collectd

I am collecting system metrics using Collectd. I am collecting measures in small intervals to get accurate values. However i want to aggregate these values locally using Statsd. Statsd should aggregate the values and send them to librato in longer intervals. This will reduce costs.

I have completed the basic setup of Collectd and Statsd. How do i send data from Collectd to Statsd?

The Statsd plugin seems to be a replacement for Statsd itself and seems not to provide this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like there is any established plugin to accomplish this.  If you're already satisfied where/how collectd is sending the data, and just want to aggregate, you can use the aggregation plugin:

https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Aggregation

If you really want to get the data into StatsD somehow, you might be able to use the collectd Network output plugin and have it point to StatsD's port (although you may have to manipulate the data somehow).

I think for the most part, though, these 2 exist in parallel, and if you needed both each daemon would send data to your librato separately, or you could consolidate by only using CollectD with the StatsD plugin.